# "\u00e1n" to "á" in PHP

Tags: php, char

I am receiving an external file with strings, I have no control over that file but I receive special characters as this (i think it's unicode?) sequence \u00e1n.

Is there anyway to convert this kind of char sequences to their "readable" counterparts?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I am calling a url that gives me a list with names of persons:

Tom\u00e1nsson\n
Eriksen\n
Gilverto\n

I am reading the names and showing them in my site.

Comment: It is already readable. The problem is that you didn't tell us *what* reads that character. Browser? Your text editor? Terminal? It's not the character's fault, or anything like that. The actual issue lies in  the target program being able to understand what's presented to it.

Comment: Is the data JSON by any chance...?

Comment: Hello, thank you, I don't know how the data is being generated, it's a feed that an external company produces for my website.

Comment: Look up what "JSON" is. Compare whether the data you receive is JSON (or RTFM of that feed if available). If so, use a JSON decoder.

Comment: The string has to be shown in the browser (for all the users to see)

Comment: No, the data is not json. it's a txt file with \n

Comment: Then show us a (complete) sample, if possible.

Comment: Here is the list:

Tom\u00e1nsson\n
Eriksen\n
Gilverto\n

I just read the names and show in my site

Comment: This very much does look like JSON encoding. You're sure it's not valid JSON? There's no `".."` around those strings? If not, then it *could* theoretically be anything that other service wants it to be. Some documentation or clarification from the 3rd party would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **EDIT**

Now, I've figured out the correct, working answer based on the article I found. Here is it:

```
function unicode2utf8($str) {
    $a=json_decode(str_replace("\n","<br>",'["'.$str.'"]'));
    return str_replace("<br>","\n",$a[0]);
}
```

PHP:

```
echo unicode2utf8("Tom\u00e1nsson\n Eriksen\n Gilverto\n");
```

Output:

```
Tománsson
 Eriksen
 Gilverto
```

---

### **ORIGINAL**

I've found an article about the same problem here ( http://www.welefen.com/php-unicode-to-utf8.html )

The solution is the following function

```
function unicode2utf8($str){
    if(!$str) return $str;
    $decode = json_decode($str);
    if($decode) return $decode;
    $str = '["' . $str . '"]';
    $decode = json_decode($str);
    if(count($decode) == 1){
            return $decode[0];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

I've tried it with

```
echo unicode2utf8("\u00e1");
```

Output:

```
á
```

Comment: Now I have a chinese character (屵〰攱)! LOL

Comment: Edited, i think now it can be the answer.

Comment: Now i tried it with the Tom... string, but it returned an empty string.   But wait a minute, and I figure out the correct answer. :)

Comment: OH NOOOOO! I cannot use JSON_DECODE :(

Comment: Why? What's the problem with that?

Comment: I've found an alternative json_decode function here http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps, but i don't know if it works or not. Try it! :)

Comment: Here is another article about using JSON functions in PHP4: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/using-json-encode-and-json-decode-in-php4/