# Combining Diacritic Marks: a + ´ don't give á but give a´

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Somehow similar to ["\u00e1n" to "á" in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117658/u00e1n-to-%C3%A1-in-php) but even [UnicodeUtils](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/unicode_utils/1.4.0/UnicodeUtils) seems not to help me.

Instead of `kara/--mardaka/` I want to have `kará--mardaká` with combined diacritic marks. Same with `aaṃśu/--pati` - I need it just `aṃśú--pati`. In my converter do I have to list all the possible combinations of vowels plus `0301` input and needed output? In the past in my JS I listed [all of them](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1we5kBbnznLn9eFe7ah-hpdClesBwLLITuwCLbJjbfrU/edit#heading=h.mwchayejsqk7).

When I get `a` instead `á` it's like I had used `00B4` (ACUTE ACCENT), but no, I went for `0301` (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT). I need to generate it in PHP to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

U+00B4 "Acute accent" is not a combining diacritic mark, and you can't expect it to be rendered like one. Use U+0301 "combining acute accent" instead.